# Images stored in laravel storage/app/protected/images are displayed but return 404

Tags: image, http-status-code-404, laravel-7, forge

The application stores images in various directories inside storage/app/protected/images directory on Laravel 7. I have had no problem displaying images retrieved from these directories on my localhost, but when I moved to the staging, I have noticed that each request returns 404 even though the image is displayed in the browser.

I have checked the backend and have the same issue with all images in the backend (admin).

the image URL structure is simple: `example.com/images/slider/image-name.png`

Here is my `ImageViewController`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Client;

    use App\Exceptions\ErrorPageException;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

    class ImageViewController extends Controller
    {
        public function getMainImage($name)
        {
            if(file_exists(storage_path('app/protected').'/images/'.$name)){
                $image = storage_path('app/protected').'/images/'.$name;
            }else{
                throw new ErrorPageException(404);
            }
            return response()->file($image);
        }

        public function getImage($type, $name)
        {
            if(file_exists(storage_path('app/protected').'/images/'.$type.'/'.$name)){
                $image = storage_path('app/protected').'/images/'.$type.'/'.$name;
            }else{
                throw new ErrorPageException(404);
            }
            return response()->file($image);
        }

    }
```

And here my route:

```
Route::get('images/{name}', 'Client\ImageViewController@getMainImage');

Route::get('images/{type}/{name}', 'Client\ImageViewController@getImage');
```

I cannot seem to figure out the problem on my own.

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

The problem appeared after including NGINX static file cache directives.

I have changed the approach and all works just fine now!

Here they are for anyone in my situation:

```
# browser caching of static assets
    location ~ /\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
        expires 30d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # CSS and Javascript
    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
      expires 1y;
      access_log off;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }
```

All of this code goes inside the `server { ... }`